# How to write many values of property css in tailwind?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I want to convert my css to tailwind but when I find many sources, there is no solution.
Here is My css

```css
.selector {
  background-size: contain, cover;
}
```

and If anyone have clue or solution for another property please feel free to comment the solution

Answer (score 2):

from the docs https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-size

you can use multiple using `bg-[]` syntax

like this

```html
<div class="bg-[length:contain,cover]"></div>
```

also, make sure you are in the NPM package tailwind.

and there isn't any space between the brackets.

> `length:` is important for making the tailwind you are referring to `size`, because bg can be color, image, or any other thing.

[image]

Comment: Demo of it working: https://play.tailwindcss.com/I1Okym89Kv

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `contain` and `cover` at the same time in CSS that is why it is also not possible in tailwind. Choose one, either `bg-contain` or `bg-cover`. Here are examples of what it does: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-size

Comment: This is false, you can use as many values as you want inside background-size https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: @TemaniAfif, thank you for your comment, but you are wrong. As you can read on the doc page you are referring to, it states: "Using the keyword values contain **or** cover". So indeed you may use multiple options for background, but not these two combined. If you look what the effect is of these options, it does not make sense to combine them.

Comment: read the full doc, that apply to a single value among the many values you can use. You can combine all the values you want. A proof: https://jsfiddle.net/gdh308zb/1/ Try it yourself and inspect the code to see that it's perfectly valid

Comment: I am not talking about the *result*. There is a ton of examples where both combined can give *good* result. It's about the validity here. You said "you cannot" and this is simply wrong because we can. I am not debating, I am correcting you based on official resource and a working example using the OP syntax. As simple as that. The syntax of the OP is valid and so is their question

Answer (score 1):

You need to [extend](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-size#customizing-your-theme) default background-sizes with your own. First argument is class name and second one is desired CSS property

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundSize: {
        'contain-cover': 'contain, cover', // here
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

and use it like `bg-contain-cover` (you may name it as you wish and use like `bg-your-custom-bg-size-name`)

[DEMO](https://play.tailwindcss.com/A5USbA8oZA)